# Implementation of Student Attendance System using Google Actions + Firebase + Raspberry PI

Tags: firebase, raspberry-pi, actions-on-google

I am trying to implement integration of Actions on Google with Raspberry Pi for Student Attendance System for my College Campus.
Thereby, I was stuck during formulation of idea, since I am not finding any way that how:

1. When Professor asks my action to mark attendance and then that will trigger Raspberry PI Software or script to mark attendance using a Fingerprint Module attached to it from students. How to do this?
2. After taking attendance of Students from Raspberry PI, how can I send it to Firebase via that Actions?

Please do help me in getting this thing sorted out! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure you can do that using Raspberry pi.
Here are the steps..
Buy a Raspberey pi3 board..
Also buy raspberry pi compatible Fingerprint module..
Then install Raspberry os on raspberry pi board...
Install library for Fingerprint sensor...

Then you should understand very important things and using this link you can get a broad knowledge.

https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi-fingerprint-sensor-interfacing

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing such great resource link! I will be looking over this carefully!